# JavaFX FXML component fill parent - like alignParent in Android

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, desktop-application, fxml

A question asked a hundred times I know but nobody seems to know how to do this.

I have a BorderPane and want to put Canvas as bottom of the BorderPane. And I want the Canvas to fill the whole bottom. I don't want to hardcode any values.
Is it even possible?

In Android I have something like alignParentTop etc. It's really unintuitive here in JavaFX.

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="pl.mg.checkers.controller.GameController"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <top>
        <HBox>
            <Button fx:id="leaveButton" text="Leave"/> 
        </HBox>
    </top>
    <bottom>
        <Canvas fx:id="canvas"/>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449932/javafx-resize-canvas-when-screen-is-resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Canvas` is not resizable. See [here](https://dlemmermann.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/javafx-tip-1-resizable-canvas/) for discussion and solution.