# JavaFX Canvas not resizing correctly inside StackPane

Tags: java, canvas, layout, javafx

Below is the `Main.class` and the `Controller.class` , i tried to make it as simpler as possible.

The program outputs the below window:
[image]

---

The black is a `StackPane` named `visualizerStackPane` and inside it is a `Canvas` named `visualizerCanvas` . **What i want to do is the `Canvas` inside the `StackPane` to be resized accordingly to the `StackPane` size substract 4** . But everything fails when you resize the window.

What you have to try...

1)Maximize the window and then normalize it back.

2)Increase the size of the window and slowly decrease it back.

Why this is happening?I have this problem 3 months now and i can't find a solution...

I have also looked [JavaFX - Resize Canvas when screen is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449932/javafx-resize-canvas-when-screen-is-resized) but the problem here seems to be different...

---

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            //Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(new Controller(), 400, 400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            //Show
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

**Controller.java:**

I have modified the Controller class to paint the Canvas and removed the bindings from `Initialize` method , it doesn't work it produces the below:

[image]

If i don't set the width and height of the Canvas manually it doesn't even get painted...I don't know why .

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Controller extends StackPane {

    @FXML
    private GridPane container;

    @FXML
    private GridPane topGridPane;

    @FXML
    private StackPane visualizerStackPane;

    @FXML
    private Canvas visualizerCanvas;

    @FXML
    private VBox topRightVBox;

    @FXML
    private StackPane mediaFileStackPane;

    @FXML
    private GridPane bottomGridPane;

    // ------------------------------

    GraphicsContext gc;
    int             canvasWidth     = 0;
    int             canvasHeight    = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Controller() {

        // ------------------------FXMLLoader ---------------------------------
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Controller.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Controller FXML can't be loaded!", ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called as soon as FXML FILE has been loaded
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        gc = visualizerCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // // VisualizerStackPane inside which visualizerCanvas is
        // visualizerCanvas.widthProperty().bind(visualizerStackPane.widthProperty().subtract(4));
        // visualizerCanvas.heightProperty().bind(visualizerStackPane.heightProperty().subtract(4));
        //

        // Add width and height change listeners
        visualizerStackPane.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,
                newValue) -> resizeVisualizerCanvas(newValue.doubleValue(), visualizerStackPane.getHeight()));

        visualizerStackPane.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue,
                newValue) -> resizeVisualizerCanvas(visualizerStackPane.getWidth(), newValue.doubleValue())

        );

        repaintCanvas();
    }

    /**
     * Repaints the Canvas
     */
    public void repaintCanvas() {

        //Clear the previous rectangle
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        // Draw the
        gc.setFill(Color.RED);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        // Draw the Line
        gc.setLineWidth(3);
        gc.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        gc.strokeLine(0, canvasHeight, canvasWidth, 0);

    }

    /**
     * Resizes the visualizerCanvas to the given values.
     *
     * @param width
     *            the width
     * @param height
     *            the height
     */
    public void resizeVisualizerCanvas(double width, double height) {
        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {

            this.canvasWidth = (int) width;
            this.canvasHeight = (int) height;

            // Print something
            System.out.println("Canvas Width is:" + width+" , Canvas Height is:"+height +" Canvas is Resizable: "+visualizerCanvas.isResizable());

            // Repaint the Canvas
            repaintCanvas();

            // ---------------------------Below i have tried several things to
            // solve the problem....

            // Set the width and height of Canvas
            visualizerCanvas.setWidth(width);
            visualizerCanvas.setHeight(height);

            // Careful with contentBias here
            prefWidth(-1);
            prefHeight(-1);

            // autosize()

            // System.out.println("Content Bias is:"+this.getContentBias())

        }
    }
}
```

---

**Controller.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Region?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root prefHeight="212.0" prefWidth="456.0" type="StackPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
   </padding>
   <children>
      <GridPane fx:id="container">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="40.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" percentHeight="60.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <GridPane fx:id="topGridPane" gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <StackPane fx:id="visualizerStackPane" style="-fx-border-color: white; -fx-border-width: 1.5; -fx-background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.95);">
                     <children>
                        <Canvas fx:id="visualizerCanvas" />
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
                  <VBox fx:id="topRightVBox" GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                     <children>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                           <children>
                              <Region style="-fx-background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.7);" />
                              <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="text here" />
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                        <StackPane fx:id="mediaFileStackPane" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" />
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </GridPane>
            <GridPane fx:id="bottomGridPane" gridLinesVisible="true" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
              <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="20.0" prefWidth="35.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="60.0" prefWidth="343.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" percentWidth="20.0" prefWidth="52.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2">
                     <children>
                        <Region style="-fx-background-color: rgb(255,255,255,0.7);" />
                        <Label alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" style="-fx-font-weight: bold;" text="text here" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" StackPane.alignment="CENTER" />
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
                  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" spacing="5.0" />
               </children>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

---

**Finally:**

> A big thanks to the person who will manage to solve this problem :).

Comment: Remove all lines from your `initialize()` method.  You are attempting to take control of layout operations yourself, which is interfering with StackPane’s ability to do its job.  Instead, you can set an additional border on the StackPane with a width of 2, or set the StackPane’s padding to 0.5 on all sides, or set the Canvas’s StackPane.margin to 0.5 on all sides.

Comment: @VGR Then how i can get the width and the height of canvas?Will canvas autoresize ? Whenever i add a ChangeListener to the `widthProperty` and `heightProperty` of the `Canvas` i am getting `-1` . I appreciate your help... :)

Comment: StackPane already sizes each child to the StackPane’s content size (the StackPane’s size minus its insets).  You don’t have to do anything.

Comment: @VGR Well then i don't know how i can  get the width and height of Canvas whenever that resize happens cause the properties do return -1 :(

Comment: I did as @VGR commented, and it resized correctly. In order to get the size of the canvas, I switched the listener to the stack pane, and printed the `newValue`. That should be the correct sizes.

Comment: @MichaelPickett If you want post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research i have found the solution . Creating a custom `Canvas` class and `@Overriding` methods from `Canvas`:

---

Very glad from the final answer on this question: [How to make canvas Resizable in javaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533556/how-to-make-canvas-resizable-in-javafx#31946816)

A link that gave me the idea: http://dlsc.com/2014/04/10/javafx-tip-1-resizable-canvas/

---

**ResizableCavas.java :**

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

class ResizableCanvas extends Canvas {

    GraphicsContext gc                  = getGraphicsContext2D();
    int             canvasWidth         = 0;
    int             canvasHeight        = 0;
    int             halfCanvasHeight    = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public ResizableCanvas() {

        // if i didn't add the draw to the @Override resize(double width, double
        // height) then it must be into the below listeners

        // Redraw canvas when size changes.
        widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("Entered WIDTH property");
            canvasWidth = (int) widthProperty().get();
        });
        heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            System.out.println("Entered HEIGHT property");

            canvasHeight = (int) heightProperty().get();
            halfCanvasHeight = canvasHeight >> 1;
        });

    }

    /**
     * Redraw the Canvas
     */
    private void draw() {

        System.out.println(" Real Canvas Width is:" + getWidth() + " , Real Canvas Height is:" + getHeight() + "\n");

        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

        gc.setStroke(Color.RED);
        gc.strokeLine(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        gc.strokeLine(0, canvasHeight, canvasWidth, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public double minHeight(double width) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public double maxHeight(double width) {
        return Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public double prefHeight(double width) {
        return minHeight(width);
    }

    @Override
    public double minWidth(double height) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public double maxWidth(double height) {
        return Double.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isResizable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(double width, double height) {
        super.setWidth(width);
        super.setHeight(height);
        draw();
    }
}
```

---

**Controller.java:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Controller extends StackPane {

    @FXML
    private GridPane container;

    @FXML
    private GridPane topGridPane;

    @FXML
    private StackPane visualizerStackPane;

    @FXML
    private VBox topRightVBox;

    @FXML
    private StackPane mediaFileStackPane;

    @FXML
    private GridPane bottomGridPane;

    // ------------------------------

    ResizableCanvas visualizerCanvas = new ResizableCanvas();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Controller() {

        // ------------------------FXMLLoader ---------------------------------
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Controller.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        loader.setRoot(this);

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Controller FXML can't be loaded!", ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called as soon as FXML FILE has been loaded
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        visualizerStackPane.getChildren().add(visualizerCanvas);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the binding from your `initialize()` method. You are attempting to take control of layout operations yourself, which stop `StackPane` doing what it is supposed to do. This will resize the `Canvas` appropriately.

You state that when you print the `width` and `height` of the `Canvas`, it returns -1. Instead of doing this, print the `width` and `height` of the container `StackPane`. Since `Canvas` is, after all, contained fully within the `StackPane`, then the `width` and `height` will be almost identical, if not identical.

Comment: Hello Michael I modified the code , everything tried is not even working.... I have changed the `Controller.java` to not have bindings , tried also not modifying the width of the `Canvas` but then it doesn't get painted.Although when i modify the width and height of the `Canvas` it gets painted as you can see in the second image :) Thanks for help...

Comment: Take out the resizeVisualizer call in your width and height property listener.

Comment: I need a way to bind the `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` to the `width` and `height` of Canvas without using Bindings.. It is for performance reasons , cause i am drawing animations in `Canvas`

Comment: Use the StackPanes width and height. The canvas will fill it out, thus its height and width are the Canvas'

Comment: Removed everything and tried even `visualizerStackPane.getWidth()` or using `layoutBounds()` . Can you provide some code which is working? :) For some reason the `Canvas` has the size of (0,0) , it doesn't resize....

Comment: Hm i see something strange... `when i call is resizable on Canvas returns false`. I can see inside the `SceneBuilder` that the Resizable check box can't be checked.... xmmm